# Lock camera 2 preview to sensor landscape in Android

Tags: android, camera, android-camera2

I have a custom camera using `Camera2` which have feature taking a picture for OCR. The problem is on orientation the Camera Preview, I need to lock it to sensor landscape (Landscape and Reverse Landscape). Everything fine on the first launch:

[image: Picture 1]

But when I rotated to reverse landscape the preview is gone wrong:

[image: Picture 2]

I've read and tried so many questions regarding this problem, but it doesn't work. I have copy whole of my camera activity in [here](https://pastebin.com/YwuxrGMW).

Comment: Did you found any solutions yet?

Comment: @sonudelhikkc not yet, for now I lock the orientation to landscape only.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly read your full source code, I think you should separate each orientation cases

```
int orientation = mActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
switch(orientation) {
    case Surface.ROTATION_0:
        mCameraRotation = mIsPortraitDevice ? CameraRotation.ROTATION_270 : CameraRotation.ROTATION_0;
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_90:
        mCameraRotation = mIsPortraitDevice ? CameraRotation.ROTATION_0 : CameraRotation.ROTATION_90;
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_180:
        mCameraRotation = mIsPortraitDevice ? CameraRotation.ROTATION_90 : CameraRotation.ROTATION_180;
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_270:
        mCameraRotation = mIsPortraitDevice ? CameraRotation.ROTATION_180 : CameraRotation.ROTATION_270;
        break;
}
```